# Visual Studio ругается на несуществующие ошибки[РЕШЕНО]

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, отладка

При компиляции кода в Vs 2019 выдает 2 ошибки, но красных подчеркиваний в коде нет.
В списке ошибок тоже пусто.
[image: лог студии]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MoveArea : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public bool IsDrag;
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventdata)
    {
        Debug.Log(1);
        Vector2 pos = transform.position - (new Vector3(eventdata.position.x, eventdata.position.y, 0)); //
        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(pos.x, pos.y + 10);//
        Debug.Log(direction);
        IsDrag = true;
    }
    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventdata)
    {
        Debug.Log(2);
        IsDrag = false;
    }
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: `new (pos.x, pos.y + 10)` -> `new Vector2(pos.x, pos.y + 10)`?

Comment: Сработало, теперь Unity компилируется без ошибок, но Vs ситуация не улучшилась  все те же 2 ошибки

Comment: Ну, вы их не показали, а "ванговать" мне ой как не хочется...

Answer (score 0):

Сменил конфигурацию решения с Debug на Release - все заработало